# Easiest way to embed java code in web content

Tags: java, web

I have made a java code in eclipse. which is running properly. Now I need to make a web interface an use that code...Please tell me which is the easiest way to do it. 
I want to know in which language I can use that java code directly to develop the web content.

Comment: in Java? you know you can write web applications in Java, right? most likely, what you want is to import your code in a new web application, rather than to copy it

Comment: Forget Java applet please... Applet are not designed for web development and they got lot of problems.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want to code something like https://ideone.com/ ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283468/web-user-interface-for-a-java-application

Answer (score -1):

First suggestion is to create an JSP interface for your code. Other possibility is to use JavaFX, as you can see for example in [Example JavaFX code for Building a Simple GUI Application](http://java.about.com/od/creatinguserinterfaces/ss/Example-Javafx-Code-For-Building-A-Simple-Gui-Application.htm).

Comment: Forget JavaFX, applets and all this stuff. Just do web.

Answer (score -1):

If you turn your Java code into a RESTful webservice then you open up the possibility to call it from any language at all, including simple Javascript in a HTML file.

Recommended reading:

Wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Java way to do RESTful webservices: https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/